# How to find sides on similar shapes (trapezia)?

Tags: geometry

[image]

I take the fact that the smallest trapezium in the figure is similar to the entire figure. Therefore using the ratio of the side lengths:

$$\frac{6}{6}=\frac{x}{x+8}$$

Why must it be:

$$\frac{3}{6}=\frac{x}{8}$$

Comment: I think it is Thales' theorem.

Comment: How did you come up with the left-hand side, $\frac 66$? There's a segment of length $6$ on the left, which is relevant (indeed it's the $6$ in $\frac 36$ in the correct formula), but the only other $6$ is at the top, which doesn't really have any proportional relationship to any of the other labeled segments except maybe the $15$ at the bottom.

Comment: I was using the whole shape and the 'top' trapezia, the 6 on the top side is shared for both

Comment: As I already tried to explain, the $6$ on top is all but completely useless in this problem. You could redraw the trapezium with top side $5$ or $7$, all other labeled sides remain unchanged, you just have to adjust the angles and the unlabeled line in the middle a little. Part of learning geometry is learning to recognize information that is _useless_ for a particular question and then _not using it._

Comment: Another good thing to learn is to recognize when you write something that cannot possibly be true. That will be a clue that you made a mistake somewhere, so you can fix it or try again. In this case, you wrote $\frac{6}{6}=\frac{x}{x+8}$, which implies $1=\frac{x}{x+8}$, which implies $x = x+8$, which implies $8=0$, which is obviously false, so you _must_ have gone wrong somewhere while you were setting up $\frac{6}{6}=\frac{x}{x+8}$.

Comment: You need to calculate the ratios with the sides between parallel sides. (*Intercept theorem*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say SOMEthing like that, but it'd have to be
$$
\frac{3}{3+6} = \frac{x}{x+8}
$$
so that you're comparing like quantities on the two sides.

Comment: can I not compare the top side of both trapezia, @JohnHughes

Comment: When you wrote "6/6", is the top "6" the flat side on top, and the bottom 6 the lower portion of the left side? On the right, youv'e got $x/(x+8)$, which is the ratio of the short part of the right edge to the full length of the right edge. You need to compare this to the ratio of the short part of something to the whole length of something if you expect equality. :)

Comment: both 6's were the flat side on top

Comment: The two trapeziums are obviously _not_ similar figures. You can tell they are not similar because they have the same top length but different bottom lengths; they also have different "right edge" lengths.